# Spring boot + MongoDB - localhost show whitelabel error

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, spring-boot, localhost

So I know there's other questions like this one however I see no solution to my problem.

Hopefully one of you can see what I am doing wrong.

When I go to localhost//:8080 I get "whitelabel error...."

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>  
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>mavenproject1</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--Spring--> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--MONGO-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>          
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--skal dette bruges?-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and my application class looks like so:

```
package com.example.mavenproject1;

import org.springframework.boot.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Steffen
 */
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    //Run a function here which dives into the mongoDB and returns the info?
    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {

        DBPopulator dbp = new DBPopulator();

        dbp.saveNew();


//        return dbp.getFil();

        return "Hey wassup";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And the DBPopulator:

```
package com.example.mavenproject1;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update;


import org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext;


/**
 *
 * @author Steffen
 */
public class DBPopulator {

    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ConnectToDB.class);
    MongoOperations mongoOperation = (MongoOperations) ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate");

    private int vers = 0;

    public void saveNew() {
        Fil f = new Fil("fil" + vers + "", new MetaData(new Date(), new Date(), 5));
        vers++;
        mongoOperation.save(f);
    };

    public String getFil(){
    // query to search user
        Query searchQuery = new Query(Criteria.where("filNavn").is("fil1"));

        Fil savedF = mongoOperation.findOne(searchQuery, Fil.class);

        List<Fil> listFiler = mongoOperation.findAll(Fil.class);



        System.out.println("Here is my file: " + savedF);

        return "File: " + savedF;
    } 
}
```

now my application "works" as in it saves new "Fil" to my mongoDB. I wanted to return them in the "Home" function in the Application class, but so far I can't get anything but "whitelabel error" out...

Thanks in advance!

**Edit

File Structure is as follows.
[image]

and the full error from the localhost//:8080 is:

Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Aug 07 16:39:18 CEST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
com/mongodb/BulkWriteException

Comment: can you please paste the whole error message and the stack trace from console.

Comment: Hi @zombie, the error message is as follows:
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Aug 07 16:39:18 CEST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
com/mongodb/BulkWriteException

but I am not getting any output in the console... If you know why that'd be a massive help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is looking for  [BulkWriteException](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/BulkWriteException.html)  which is available from 2.12 mongo driver version.

Solution 1

At least upgrade to

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Solution 2 (better)

Remove

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and keep

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
     <version>1.10.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

pulls in the correct dependency which is 2.4.x mongo driver.

Solution 3 (best)

Remove

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
     <version>1.10.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

add

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

pulls both the compatible spring mongo and mongo dependency which is 2.4.x mongo driver.

Comment: If I remove the:

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
        I get an error in my "connectToDB" class. The error being with these two : import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient; it says the package com.mongodb doesn't exist

Comment: Maven as part of [spring mongo dependency](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/1.10.x/pom.xml#L32) should pull in the mongo driver dependency and try forcing maven update if it is not pulling the dependency.